# Ubuntu 16.04 sometimes reboot when I shut it down

Tags: 16.04, shutdown, reboot

when I select from menu in Ubuntu 16.04 the shutdown, sometimes it happens the computer is rebooting after finished shutdown instad of power off.

How to fix this?

Comment: Does `shutdown -h now`  works?

Comment: when I make a `sudo shutdown -h now` I could not observe that mysterious behaviour yet...